# What's the type of the anonymous function in Lua?

Tags: lua

In Lua reference manual, it says that every value has a type which might be one of the local, global, table field types. My question is what's the type of the anonymous  function in Lua? What life cycle the anonymous function has? I just show an example.

```
local co = coroutine.create( function () print "hi" end )

print(coroutine.status(co))
```

Comment: It is weird that OP is asking for function and in his code he has coroutine...

Comment: All functions in Lua are anonymous; they are first-class types and don't store anything about where they were created (debug messages get their "name" by looking at how you call the function). But this is trivial to check yourself: `print(type(function() end))`

Comment: Yes, all functions are anonymous. The "[syntactic sugar](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11)" statements might make it look like Lua has declarations for named function but there is no such thing as a named function nor a function declaration. A function is value that is created when an expression that is comprised of a function definition is evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing values and variables. Values have data types like string, table, function, etc. Call the `type` function on an expression to get its type.

Variables refer to values but don't have a data type. The categories you are referring to: global, local and table field are not data types.

The concepts are orthogonal. For example: A local value can be of any data type; A function can be referred to by a global, local or table field.

As explained elsewhere (manual and comments), all function values are anonymous so that is not a separate category.

The lifetime of a value is always from the time it was first evaluated until no variable references it.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is some mix of concepts here. As others already said, Lua only has anonymous functions, which have type `function` (`type(function() end) == 'function'`). These anonymous functions can be assigned to variables, which can then be used to call functions; these are conveniently used as "names" for functions, but they are really names for variables that store values of type "function".

In terms of their lifecycle, they are not different from any other variable: if the function is no longer reacheable, it will be garbage collected at some point. For example, a function inside this block `do local func = function() end end` is not reachable from outside of the block and will be collected.

The example you have shown creates a coroutine, which takes a function and creates a value of type `thread`: `type(coroutine.create(function() end)) == "thread"`. These coroutines may be in different states and their state is returned by `coroutine.status` function; in your case it's going to be "suspended".

Answer (score 0):

A function has the type of `function`. In Lua, functions are first class citizen: [First-Class Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)

In actual memory, the function is just some block of memory that contains set of commands (similar to any other type e.g. integers)